# PHP e Banco de Dados não atualiza, uso do UPDATE - SET - WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estou tendo problemas com o código que estou desenvolvendo, peço que faça a alteração no banco de dados, no entanto, não é feita nenhuma alteração no meu BD.

Segue o código:

```
<?php

$id = $_POST['id']; //Variável de controle.
$nroproduto = $_POST['nroproduto']; // Não desejo alterar o nroproduto.
$nomeproduto = $_POST['nomeproduto']; //Variável para determinar o nome do produto.
$categoria = $_POST['categoria']; //Variável para determinar a categoria do produto.
$quantidade = $_POST['quantidade']; //Variável para determinar a quantidade do produto.
$fornecedor = $_POST['fornecedor']; //Variável para determinar o fornecedor do produto.

 $sql = "UPDATE `estoque` SET `nomeproduto`='$nomeproduto',`categoria`='categoria',`quantidade`='quantidade',`fornecedor`='fornecedor' WHERE id_estoque = $id";

 $atualizar = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"> //bootstrap link

<div class="container" style="width: 400px">
        <center>
        <h3>Atualizado com sucesso!</h3>
        <div style="margin-top: 10px">
            <a href="lista_produtos.php" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" style="color: #fff">Voltar</a>
        </div>      
        </center>

</div>
```

Comment: Posta a parte do código que esta sendo usado para que possamos ajudar.

Comment: Você garantiu que todos os dados estão vindo via post ? tentou fazer um var_dump neles ?

Answer (score 0):

Faz assim que dar certo:

```html
<?php

$id = $_POST['id']; //Variável de controle.
$nroproduto = $_POST['nroproduto']; // Não desejo alterar o nroproduto.
$nomeproduto = $_POST['nomeproduto']; //Variável para determinar o nome do produto.
$categoria = $_POST['categoria']; //Variável para determinar a categoria do produto.
$quantidade = $_POST['quantidade']; //Variável para determinar a quantidade do produto.
$fornecedor = $_POST['fornecedor']; //Variável para determinar o fornecedor do produto.

mysqli_query($conexao, "UPDATE estoque set nomeproduto='$nomeproduto', categoria='categoria', quantidade='quantidade', fornecedor='fornecedor' WHERE id_estoque = $id");

?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"> //bootstrap link

<div class="container" style="width: 400px">
        <center>
        <h3>Atualizado com sucesso!</h3>
        <div style="margin-top: 10px">
            <a href="lista_produtos.php" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" style="color: #fff">Voltar</a>
        </div>      
        </center>

</div>
```